# Always keep desktop files aligned on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Vostro 3546.

I want to keep desktop icons aligned automatically, even after reboot:

[image: like this]

Thanks in advance.